# Spider-man histories between Civil War and Secret Invasion

Tags: marvel, comics, suggested-order, spider-man

Reading New Avengers #27, We can see Peter using that black costume and reading The Amazing Spider man you just see him using that costume after its aunt was shot.

I'm confused about it, because the last storyline before them introduce "Brand New Day" is "One more day", besides when will I see The Amazing Spider man corresponding to the New Avengers giving an introduction to Secret Invasion? Is There another issue that introduce him to the "Outlaw" Avengers

Currently, I'm on The Amazing Spider-man #555.

Update:

BTW, When Mephisto has done its weird magic demon, everybody doesn't know who is spider man, but Civil War did happen, as well as Rogers's death, so he still makes part of the avengers and they're hiding out at Dr. Strange's house. Am I right? If yes, Where Can I follow up them going to Strange's house?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different questions here.

The first is that yes, after Civil War Spider-Man reverts to his black costume temporarily after Aunt May gets shot.  This happens in Amazing Spider-Man issues #549-#543.  Right after this arc are the "One More Day" and "Brand New Day" story lines.  Spider-Man's costume change to black is accurately reflected in the New Avengers comics as well and reverts back to his traditional costume after the "Back In Black" story line concludes.

Next is the question about Secret Invasion.  The Secret Invasion storyline ran through New Avengers issues #38-47.  Now as far as Spider-Man, I don't recall any Secret Invasion story line running through the main Amazing Spider-Man title (probably due to the already large status quo shift brought about by Brand New Day).  However, there was a 3-issue mini-series that addressed Spider-Man and his involvement in Secret Invasion.  It was called Secret Invasion: The Amazing Spider-Man.

The final question deals with Mephisto and the removal of Spider-Man's identity.  The plot that runs through the "One More Day" story line is a cross over between the different Spider-Man books at the time.  This is the order of reading for "One More Day":

- Amazing Spider-Man #544
- Friendly Neighborhood Spider-Man #24
- The Sensational Spider-Man (vol. 2) #41
- Amazing Spider-Man #545

In order to get the full story you need to read the other two comics that are not part of Amazing Spider-Man.  Now the final part of your question deals with Mephisto and the deal Peter and Mary Jane make with him.  The deal dissolves Mary Jane and Peter's marriage, saves Aunt May's life, and reverses Peter's public reveal that he is Spider-Man which he makes in Civil War.  Although the Avengers do not remember his identity or his marriage, all other status quo's were preserved in the Marvel Universe.

I hope this helps and happy reading!

Comment: He puts on the black outfit right at the end of Civil War, one of the final panels shows him wearing it.

Comment: Added more clarification to my answer, thank you!

Comment: Thank you B17, one more thing, Why does marvel create several titles of spider man? Why does not it keep everything in one title?

Comment: Yes, it was very confusing when these books came out. The answer is really that it depends. In the case of the Secret Invasion: Spider-Man book, there were so many different plot threads being introduced in the Brand New Day story, I think that Marvel thought it would detract from the ongoing series by focusing in on Secret Invasion because readers wanted more answers on what was happening in the "rebooted" Spider-Man universe that no longer contains Mary Jane and Peter being married.